# How to enable generating reference assembly in C# through CMake

Tags: c#, cmake

I'm looking for a way to enable CMake C# target to generate reference assembly.
I'm using this CMake script right now, but it doesn't work:

```
set(SCRIPT_ENGINE_TARGET ScriptEngine CACHE INTERNAL "")

file(GLOB_RECURSE FILES_TO_COMPILE
    "src/*.cs"
)

project(ScriptEngine VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CSharp)

add_library(ScriptEngine SHARED ${FILES_TO_COMPILE})
set_property(TARGET ScriptEngine PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.7.2")

target_compile_options(${SCRIPT_ENGINE_TARGET} PRIVATE "/refout /deterministic")

set_target_properties(ScriptEngine PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Resources/scripting/bin"
)
```

I also tried to pass `-refout -deterministic`, but it doesn't work as well. I'm using MSBuild generator, since it is required to build CMake C# projects.